# Visual Basic How to skip a line when you find a string (Line Input)

Tags: vba

How do I skip a line when finding a string

```
 Open Me.FilePath For Input As #lFileNo
    bOpenedCSVFiles = True
    Do Until EOF(lFileNo)

        Line Input #lFileNo, currentStr
```

If Instr(currentStr,"Blah") Then
Skip the line and read the next one

so are yuo saying this

```
Do Until EOF(lFileNo)
    Line Input #lFileNo, currentStr

 If Not InStr(currentStr, "Scenario") Then

'Check the scenario number
    If Me.FieldSeparator.Value = eFieldSeparator.Comma Then
        s = Split(currentStr, ",")
    Else
        s = Split(currentStr, ";")
    End If

    If CDbl(RemoveQuotes(s(LBound(s)))) = Message.ScenarioID Then
        Exit Do
    Else
    End If

End If
```

Comment: have you just considered reversing your `If`?

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: check out the `Not` keyword.

Comment: maybe I am missing something, will look up the NOT word but how will that allow me to skip a row?

Comment: you just mangle your logic around

Answer (score -1):

Look up return value of "Instr"-Function. When "StringToSearch" is not found you get a certain return value. then check on this value and skip the line if "StringToSearch" was not found

Comment: Yes but how do I skip the line?

Comment: you can skip line with "vbCrLf"